# cordova (visual studio) ios plugin with custom framework not packaged?

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, frameworks, visual-studio-cordova

tried things from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246769/vs-mda-custom-ios-framework-in-plugin)  , did not work for me.

Basically I am writing a custom plugin for ios, using cordova tool (v5.4) for Visula Studio, and I need to reference a framework (with my dynamic libs). Following instructions, everything built ok, but the app aborts on launching.
By looking at the size of ipa file, looks like my libs/framework are not being packaged (if they were, the size would have been significantly larger).
Here is how my plugin.xml  looks like

```
<config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
  <feature name="myCDVPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="myCDVPlugin" />
  </feature>
</config-file>

<header-file src="src/ios/myTest.h" />
<source-file src="src/ios/myTest.m" />

<framework src="src/ios/myLibs.framework" custom ="true"/>

<framework src="UIKit.framework" />
<framework src="Foundation.framework" />
```

BTW, here is the crash log dumped from the device--

Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: @rpath/myLibs.framework/myLibs
Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/77A1CF1C-0C2B-4EBC-A2AB-3CF362E0CD9D/com.test.app/test
Reason: image not found
Dyld Version: 353.12

Comment: update: was able to dump the crash log on my ipad, clearly states could not load library(the custom framework), does not exist in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when i tries to embed a custom swift framework to my project.
What worked for me is to go to the project build settings and change the 'Embedded Content Contains Swift Code' to 'YES'.
Hope it works for you.